# How do I change a value in an instance of a Typescript class?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, es6-class, react-typescript

I have a Fruit class:

```
export class Fruit {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}

    public changeName(_name: string): void {
        console.log('changing name')
        this.name = _name
    }
}
```

And I implement it like so:

```
import React from 'react'
import { Fruit } from '../classes/fruit'

const HomePage = () => {
    let fruit = new Fruit(1, 'apple')

    return (
        <div>
            {fruit.name} <----- I am expecting this to update on the DOM when i click the button *********
            <button onClick={() => fruit.changeName('banana')}>
                change the name
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}

export default HomePage
```

But when I click the button, the fruit name on the screen does not change. It stays as 'apple' . Does anyone know what I am doing wrong? I am new to Typescript

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some notes:

- React functional components do not work like that. If your data changes over time, you need to define some state, with a hook: `const [fruit, setFruit] = React.useState(initialFruit)`.
- That still won't work, as your `fruit` is a mutable object, React does not "see" in-place imperative updates. Not ideal, but you could fool React by using an object wrapper as the state value: `{ value: someFruit }` (this works because in JS `{ value: 1 } !== { value: 1 }`.
- Consider writing classes with immutable setters (`public changeName(name: string): Fruit`), and you'll be able to write nice declarative code like this: `<button onClick={() => setFruit(fruit.changeName('banana'))}>`.

```
export class Fruit {
    constructor(public id: number, public name: string) {}

    public changeName(name: string): Fruit {
        return new Fruit(this.id, name)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am 99% of the way tracking you but i can't seem to get it to compile. I'm not sure where you are creating new class instance that you use to set the useState etc. or even if you are creating a class instance to set as useState. Anyway you could provide the code for your example that allows declarative changeName call?

Comment: ok so basically my problem is i'm mutating an immutable object which means React doesn't know it's supposed to re-render. Ok so then what would you say would be best practice? This seems a little hacky. Would you maybe just put your properties in classes and leave the functions on the react compoennt? or do you think there is value to having related methods in the class as well? I've always just done plain react js with useState etc. Trying to learn better practices to clean up/harden my code. Maybe I am trying to mix functional programming with oop and it is not mixing well.

Comment: Not sure I follow, but that's not a hacky approach, even if not using React, you simply don't touch existing objects, you create new ones. On immutable classes, "setters" simply return new instances. That's the functional approach, which usually leads to more declarative, clear code, as you can follow the workflow with no in-place updates happening all over the codebase. Search for "javascript functional programming immutable" in google.

Comment: > do you think there is value to having related methods in the class as well. Yes, an object should provide lifecycle/update methods; otherwise, the code using it will be more verbose and typically will break encapsulation.

Comment: but isn't changing the entire object in React considered bad for performance because that makes everything have to re-render as opposed to just one piece of the dom?

Comment: ahhh wait it only re-renders if a value changes right, it doesn't necessarily re-render just because it's a new object

Comment: Indeed,  these are different things. You *must* create new values so React re-renders, that's the whole point. The way it's done (using a virtual DOM or whatever) is an implementation detail.

Comment: Now that all of the methods in the class will return new objects, the methods should be side effect free right? So for example when i changeName i also need to hit the api to change the name in the db. I should do that in the react component in useEffect right? Would be nice to be able to hit the api in the class.

Comment: That's correct: in React, side-effects should be executed only inside a `useEffect` block. You may add an effectful `save` method to the class, or you could create a `someFruitRepository.save(fruit)` that isolates the model/entity of the persistence (which is an implementation detail). At some point, you can dive into hex/clean architectures.

Answer (score 3):

So, here's the thing. This isn't going to work.

---

First of all, any variables created in a react functional component's render function only exist during that render. So when you do:

```
let fruit = new Fruit(1, 'apple')
```

Then every single time your component renders you create a new `Fruit` with an `id` of `1` a name of `"apple"`. Any changes you make to that object after the render will never be seen, because to be seen the component would need to re-rerender, which makes a new `Fruit` from scratch.

---

The way you get around this is to use "state" which preserves values between component renders.

So instead, let's say you had this:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    let [fruit, setFruit] = useState(new Fruit(1, 'apple'))
    //...
}
```

But the problem is that state is expected to be *immutable*, which means if the state were to change it expects a new object entirely, and it's forbidden to change a piece of the state.

This is because react can't tell if anything actually change in state unless you replace the state entirely.

So to fix that you would need to set a brand new object when you change the state.

This should work:

```
const HomePage = () => {
    let [fruit, setFruit] = useState(new Fruit(1, 'apple'))

    return (
        <div>
            {fruit.name}
            <button onClick={() => setFruit(new Fruit(fruit.id, 'banana')}>
                change the name
            </button>
        </div>
    )
}
```

---

But that's kid of annoying. This is why it's not recommended to put mutable instances in state. And that means there usually isn't much need for instances of a class at all, and it's usually far simpler to just store objects in state.

```
// declare state
let [fruit, setFruit] = useState({ id: 1, name: 'apple' })

// set state
setFruit({ ...fruit, name: 'banana' })
```